# AngularJS Passing ng-repeat value to ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

Angular 1.5

I am trying to pass noteNumber into a function call in ng-click.

How is that bound? This is in error.

```
    <span ng-repeat="noteNumber in row.Notes">
        <a href="#" ng-click="showNote({{noteNumber}})">{{noteNumber}}</a><span ng-show="!$last">,&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
```

Comment: your mistake are on the param of your method or event , not set with {{}} the object , set like simple variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **`ng-click="showNote(noteNumber)"`** and you'd be fine!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `{{}}` markup in `ng-click` - both the function and any arguments you pass it are assumed to be part of whatever the scope is when that template is loaded.  So:

`ng-click="showNote(noteNumber)"`